# How can I get my fontSize in pixels in React Native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, text, fonts

So, what I need to do is to get font size of my text, that I set in the styles:

```
text: {
    fontSize: 25,
  }
```

I made this by converting pt in px:

```
const TIME_HEIGHT = styles.text.fontSize * 1.34;
```

But that doesn't work the same as I expect it to work. Is there any methods to get the font size of my text and use this size later in code?

Comment: what exactly is your requiremet, usually fontsize is something you define for a text,

Answer (score 0):

try whit this lib.
"Measure text accurately before laying it out and get font information from your App (Android and iOS)."
https://github.com/aMarCruz/react-native-text-size